# Calling `this` in angular-meteor

Tags: angular-meteor

I noticed that `console.log(this.object)` will return `undefined` if I call a function from the Controller, but if I used a button in the UI to invoke it, it will return the object. 
When `this` is inspected, the `this.object` `invoke property getter` which probably is what happens when I use the button to call my function. 
Why is this happening and how can I access the `this.object` from within the Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this might not be the best solution, but getting the `object` by calling for the collection in `this.autorun` solves the issue